# I am trying to create a button to delete a row of data selected from MySQL using PHP and AJAX.

Tags: php, ajaxform

As the title suggests, I've created the button and have it located as the last column in the table.  The table is pulled from MySQL and displays all the values properly.  There's also another form for new entries, which works fine.

I've run my code through the proper validator tools online, and they pass without error.  So, I'm wondering where my issue is that it's not passing the value of the row to be deleted.  Or really, what overall is incorrect or if there's a better way to code this.  I'm fairly new to PHP and especially AJAX, so I'm wondering where I'm going wrong here?  Thanks in advance, and if more info is needed, then I'll gladly abide.

Here's the code for the HTML and PHP:

```
<?php 

@$db = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', 'pwdpwd', 'pet_shop');
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
    {
        echo 'Cannot connect to database: ' . mysqli_connect_error();
    }
else 
{
    $groomings = 'SELECT * from grooming';
    $result = $db->query($groomings);
}
?>
        <table align="center" border="1">
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>First Name</th>
                <th>Last Name</th>
                <th>Address</th>
                <th>City</th>
                <th>State</th>
                <th>Zip</th>
                <th>Phone</th>
                <th>Email</th>
                <th>Pet Type</th>
                <th>Breed</th>
                <th>Pet Name</th>
                <th>Neutered/Spayed</th>
                <th>Pet Age</th>
                <th>Edit/Delete</th>
            </tr>

<?php
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc())

    {
        echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td>' . $row['GroomingID'] . '</td>';
        echo '<td>' . $row['FirstName'] . '</td>';
        echo '<td>' . $row['LastName'] . '</td>';
        echo '<td>' . $row['Address'] . '</td>';
        echo '<td>' . $row['City'] . '</td>';
        echo '<td>' . $row['State'] . '</td>';
        echo '<td>' . $row['Zip'] . '</td>';
        echo '<td>' . $row['PhoneNumber'] . '</td>';
        echo '<td>' . $row['Email'] . '</td>';
        echo '<td>' . $row['PetType'] . '</td>';
        echo '<td>' . $row['Breed'] . '</td>';
        echo '<td>' . $row['PetName'] . '</td>';
        echo '<td>' . $row['NeuteredOrSpayed'] . '</td>';
        echo '<td>' . $row['PetAge'] . '</td>';
        echo '<td>' . '<button action="delete.php" class="del_btn" rel="'.$row["GroomingID"].'">' . 'Delete' . '</button>' . '</td>';
        echo '</tr>';
    }
?>
```

And the Jquery/Ajax:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.del_btn').click(function(){
       var del_id = $(this).attr('rel');
       $.post('delete.php', {delete_id:del_id}, function(data) {
          if(data == 'true') {
            $('#'+del_id).remove();
          } else {
            alert('Could not delete!');
          }
       });
    });
  });
</script>

        </table>
<?php
    $result->free();
    $db->close();
?>
```

And here's the delete.php file to run the query:

```
<?php
function dbString($string)
{
    $string=trim($string);
    if (get_magic_quotes_gpc())
    {
        return $string;
    }
    else
    {
        return addslashes($string);
    }
}


@$db = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', 'pwdpwd', 'pet_shop');
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
    {
        echo 'Cannot connect to database: ' . mysqli_connect_error();
    }

if(isset($_POST['delete_id']) && !empty($_POST['delete_id'])) 
{
    $delete_id = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['delete_id']);
    $result = mysql_query("DELETE FROM grooming WHERE GroomingID=".$delete_id);
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body
onload="document.createElement('form').submit.call(document.getElementById('newEntry'))">
    <form action="admin.php" id="newEntry">
    <input type="submit" value="confirm">
    </form>
</body>
```

Comment: You can delete that `dbString()` function - magic quotes is a very legacy feature, and is no longer recommended. I'd suggest removing the `@` error suppression operator too.

Answer (score 0):

In your actual code you're trying to delete an HTML element that doesn't exist

```
$('#'+del_id).remove();
```

I don't see anywhere on your code an element with this kind of ID. Try do this :

```
<?php
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc())

    {
        echo '<tr id="'.$row['GroomingID'].'">'; // <-- HERE
        echo '<td>' . $row['GroomingID'] . '</td>';
```

Also, you should put all your javascript code in the `<head>` section of your html page, not in the `<body>`

Comment: I've added the id to the row, and made the change in the JQuery to have it be $('delete_id').remove();
And removed the dbstring function as well as the @.  However it still won't pass the variables through.